# How to upload multipart image from ios to server using node.js (socket script)

Tags: ios, node.js, socket.io, image-uploading, multipartform-data

I need to upload image from my ios application to server using node socket script.Below is my script that i have tried.I could not identify the issue.Please help me if any thing wrong or missing in script side or ios side.

```
socket.on('Upload_Image', function(data)
{
    var multer  = require('multer')
    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, 'uploads/')
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
      }
    })

    var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single(data.file);
    console.log(data.file);

    app.post('/',  function (req, res) 
    {
        upload(req,res,function(req,res)
        {
            if(err)
            {
                console.log("error uploading file");
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("uploaded");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Above code - > data is the dictionary that i am passing from ios and data.file is the parameter name.

uploads -> is a folder where i need to upload image

==> ios code to call socket event

```
let msgDictionary = [
    "file":UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageData)!];                  
APP_DELEGATE.socketIOHandler?.socket?.emit("Upload_Image",msgDictionary)
```

Alternate suggestions are also welcome.